# Implement php into WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Implementing php inside WordPress proves more difficult than I've expected.
I've made a file where all my useful functions are in, called `useful_functions.inc.php`, like data validation etc.

When I run my script I get to see a form and when the user submits the form all the user input gets checked via the `useful_functions.inc.php`.

Outside Wordpress this all works perfect, but inside is an other story.
At the moment I don't even get to see my form. Am I complete missing this up or am I missing a small detail?

```
<?php
include_once ('scripts/useful_functions.inc.php');
global $wpdb; 

if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")&& $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== "" && $emailErr== "" && $telErr== "" && $afileErr== "") {
    try { 
        $table = $wpdb->prefix.'sollicitaties'; 
        $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['afile']['name']; 
        $file_size = $_FILES['afile']['size']; 
        $file_type = $_FILES['afile']['type']; 
        $file_loc = $_FILES['afile']['tmp_name']; 
        $folder="wp-content/themes/jobify-extended/uploads/"; 
        $data = array( 
            'voornaam' => $_POST['avoornaam'], 
            'familienaam' => $_POST['afamilienaam'], 
            'email' => $_POST['email'], 
            'tel' => $_POST['tel'], 
            'file' => rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['afile']['name'], 
            'size' => $_FILES['afile']['size'], 
            'type' => $_FILES['afile']['type'], 
        ); 
        $new_size = $file_size/1024; 
        $new_file_name = strtolower($file); 
        $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name); 
        $format = array( 
            '%s', 
            '%s' 
        ); 

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) 
        { 
            $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format,$folder); 
            if($success){ 
            ?> 
               <script>
                alert('successfully uploaded');
                </script>
                <?php

                exit();
              }
            }
          catch(PDOException $e)
              {
              echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
              }

          $conn->null;

    }

    else {?>

        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>Voornaam</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $voornaamErr;?></span>
                    <input type="text" name="voornaam" value="">
            </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>Familienaam</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $familienaamErr;?></span>
                    <input type="text" name="familienaam" value="<?= isset($_POST['familienaam']) ? $_POST['familienaam'] : ''; ?>">
            </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->


            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>Email Adres</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>">
            </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>Telefoon/GSM</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $telErr;?></span>
                    <input type="text" name="tel" value="<?= isset($_POST['tel']) ? $_POST['tel'] : ''; ?>">
            </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>CV</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $afileErr;?></span>
                    <input type="file" name="afile" >
            </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

        <button type="submit" class="button button-block" />Get Started</button>
        </form>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @vaso123 I get a WordPress page only with header....the rest of the page is blank

Answer (score 0):

You should use a plugin for a form, for example [contact form 7](https://he.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/).  Or develop code that would get the form data via [wp-ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) or [wp rest api](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

That how usually its done in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/exec-php/

or this one:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/

or...
https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-everywhere/

For in the past I used the first one and it worked fine.